# Hive: insert data from a program but not a data file?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to load data from output of a program but not a existed data file. here's what I want:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    X STRING);

INSERT OVERWRITE MyTable
    BY PROGRAM "python MyProgram.py";  -- #!/usr/bin/python
                                       -- print 'hello'
                                       -- print 'world'

SELECT X FROM MyTable;                 -- I will get 2 records:
                                       --   hello
                                       --   world
```

but it seems hive doesn't provide such `INSERT ... BY PROGRAM` method. is there an alternative way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

What I have used in the past is the Hadoop HDFS Rest Api *(http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html)*. I run my program (.py) from the shell and then it pushes the data into HDFS/Hive via the Api. If your Hive table is already set up then you can overwrite the existing Hive file.

Another approach I have used is a program (.py, .sh etc) creates the data into a temp file and then you can add that file using a Hive command and delete the temp file afterward.

**Edit**:

In response to your comment saying you don't have access to the shell, you could perhaps try to utilize the custom Map/Reduce functionality in Hive *(https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Tutorial scroll to the bottom to 'Custom Map/Reduce Scripts')* and pass into the map-reduce some dummy data that is to be ignored and write your .py script in the form of a reduce and just get it to emit your required data instead.

Comment: Added a suggestion in my answer to your problem.